# Wiznet W5100 and Realtek RTL8363NB-VB-CG board issue

Tags: pcb-design, switches, ethernet, rj45, rp2040

I've built a PCB connecting one of the ports of the RTL8363NB-VB-CG to the W5100 mimicking a ethernet cable on board, I used a RP2040 a Wiznet 5100S-L and the Realtek RTL8363NB-VB-CG.The problem that I'm facing it even though I can easily start up the RP2040 and program the W5100, I observe the activity LED and the Link LED of the W5100 constantly on, and no response to ping (with the proper sw tested on a commercial w5100 board) connencting to one of the other available ports on the Realtek side.

here the schematics

[image: RP2040 SCHEMATICS]

[image: W5100 SCHEMATICS]

[image: REALTEK SCHEMATICS]

I know that RP2040 and the W5100 are working fine, I can program them and they behave as expected (proven via oscilloscope and leds).

EDIT 1: I've used two transformers H1102NLT back to back to simulate the two rj45 connections on the signal path.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't need to crossover tx/Rx?  I am not 100% sure either way, so just a thought.

Comment: Also when I have done this in the past I have ended up using either capacitor coupling from chip to chip (no pulse transformers at all) or two back to back pulse transformers.  I am not sure what all the components in the signal path are, perhaps you can explain them in your question?

Comment: @RobinIddon There are two H1102NLT magnetics on the signal path to emulate the rj45 connections

Comment: Look at the w5100 reference design.  I think on the 5100 side the centre tap needs to be connected to 3.3v.  There are two types of phy.  Some need the pull up and some don't.  (I don't know about the realtek part, it might need this or it might not).

Comment: You say you are connecting to a RTL8363 but there is some other chip in the schematics. Are the schematics correct? The 8363 has two gigabit ports, so how were you able to connect three 10/100M links to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one difference to the reference schematics is the Wiznet transformer CT connection on pins 2 and 7. It should be connected to 3.3V.

The TX pair of a chip usually connects to TX pair on connector. The RTL chip supports Auto-MDIX to swap it, even if the Wiznet doesn't. You have wired them weirdly. Chip TX should be wired to RX of another chip.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed it!

Connecting pin 2 and & to 3.3V the chip starts behaving normally!

There are still some issues but I will try to investigate them first before asking!